# Scope of variables to callback functions

Tags: node.js, scope

I'm making a simple server in node.js using the TLS module. So far so good, clients are able to connect, send data, and disconnect from the server. However, I want to print the client's IP address when disconnecting from the server. As it stands, I'm able to print the client's IP address from outside the event callback functions, but I can't do so within the callbacks (check `on('end)`).

```
var tls = require('tls');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = tls.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('server-key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('server-cert.pem'),
}, function(cleartextStream) {
    cleartextStream.setEncoding('utf8');

    /*
     * Error receiving data.
     */
    cleartextStream.on('error', function (exception) {

    });

    /*
     * Signal that it is safe to write again.
     */
    cleartextStream.on('drain', function () {

    });

    /*
     * New data received.
     */
    cleartextStream.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('New data: '+data);
    });

    /*
     * Remote client disconnected.
     */
    console.log(cleartextStream.remoteAddress); // This prints the IP address correctly.

    cleartextStream.on('end', function () {
        console.log(cleartextStream.remoteAddress); // This prints undefined.
    });

    /*
     * Server is shutting down.
     */
    cleartextStream.on('close', function () {

    });
});

server.listen(8000, function() {
  console.log('Server listening.');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the `remoteAddress` property of `cleartextStream` is removed prior to the `'end'` event firing.  So capture the remote address so it's still available in your `'end'` event callback:

```
var remoteAddress = cleartextStream.remoteAddress;
cleartextStream.on('end', function () {
    console.log(remoteAddress);
});
```